# How to leave the existing graphics on a JComponent during each call of paintComponent

Tags: java, swing, awt, paintcomponent, jcomponent

I'm currently attempting to paint to a JComponent several times from a public method which calls the "paintComponent" method in order to place several shapes onto the JComponent, as if it had been painted to within a local context. (Don't ask why.) Whenever I attempt this, however, the JComponent is wiped before the new shape is drawn, leaving only the new shape. Is there a way the contents of the JComponent can be held over between calls of paintComponent, or is there an entirely different approach to take which achieves the same result?

No matter the solution, I need to be able to draw any given shape onto the JComponent using a public method, and have the contents of the JComponent be maintained between additions.

Here's my code for the JComponent in question:

```
package imageProcessor.elements;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;


public class ImageElement extends JComponent {

    private Shape shapeToBeDrawn;
    private Color shapeColor;

    public ImageElement(int width, int height) {
        this.setSize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D)g;

        if (shapeToBeDrawn != null) {
            graphics.setColor(shapeColor);
            graphics.fill(shapeToBeDrawn);
        }
    }

    public void drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color color) {
        shapeToBeDrawn = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
        shapeColor = color;
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: Save all the shapes in an array or `List`, and draw them one after the other in the single `paintComponent` method.

Comment: You can use a BufferedImage

Comment: See: [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two common ways to do custom painting.

Comment: *"(Don't ask why.)"* Done! For free with that offer, I'll ignore the question.